# Migrating from SBS 2003 to SBS 2008

Tags: windows-sbs-2008, windows-sbs-2003

I have installed SBS 2008 STD and just realized that for migration I had to create a answerfile.

We just want to migrate the users and mailboxes (From SBS 2003) ; is there a way I can do this without re-installing and running the user migration on the new box.

Kind Regards

PS : Do we have to have the same domain name for the user migration or we can change the domain name.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, migration from SBS 2003 to 2008 requires the answer file when installing the SBS 2008 Server. Unless you follow the steps in the Microsoft [SBS 2008 migration guide](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=52b7ea63-78af-4a96-811e-284f5c1de13b&displaylang=en) and [checklist](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/thankyou.aspx?familyId=f67148da-cba8-4222-8ae5-136a6597a340&displayLang=en), then the migration will fail. It is not possible to change the domain name when migrating.

Otherwise you could [Exmerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=429163EC-DCDF-47DC-96DA-1C12D67327D5&displaylang=en) the mailboxes to .PST files from the SBS 2003 server, and use the [User State Migration Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=799AB28C-691B-4B36-B7AD-6C604BE4C595&displaylang=en) for the user profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply ;

So, in order for a successful migration, I will create the answer file, make sure the two sbs 2003 servers are online (the client has two sbs 2003) ; it will then take care of itself ?

Also, would I need to re-partition the storage or I would have the option to just specify/select C: (100GB) and it will install on it ?

They have Exchange running on both of them and some business specific apps are installed.

Also, with the two tools you have mentiones USMT and Exmerge, are they reliable and would be a good option or shall I just create the answer file and get the server on site and do the migration that way.

Its my first time with SBS and Migration so just wanted to get expert advises and any other options/advises you may have to look for.

Also, is there a way to disable the NAP feature so that our client's remote worker can use any laptop (Windows based) to connect to the sbs vpn feature (if yes, can you please guide me where to disable it).

would be grateful for your suggestions and help

Comment: The migration tool will only migrate one SBS 2003 server.